# Transform an object (map) into a distinct list with terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform0.11

With Terraform, is it possible to convert an object something like

```
locals {
  data = {
    "project1" = {
      user_assigned           = ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
     }
    "project2" = {
      user_assigned           = ["user2", "user3", "user4"]
     }
  }
```

to an output like

```
user1 = ["project1"]
user2 = ["project1","project2"]
user3 = ["project1","project2"]
user4 = ["project2"]
```

Note that data is an object with maps of keys(projects) and values(user_assigned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dynamically create fully independent variables. Instead you can create a map in  few ways. One way would be with the help of [transpose](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/transpose.html) and [zipmap](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/zipmap.html):

```
output "test1" {
    value = transpose(zipmap(keys(local.data), values(local.data)[*].user_assigned))
}
```

Resulting in:

```
test1 = tomap({
  "user1" = tolist([
    "project1",
  ])
  "user2" = tolist([
    "project1",
    "project2",
  ])
  "user3" = tolist([
    "project1",
    "project2",
  ])
  "user4" = tolist([
    "project2",
  ])
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works. However I am unable to get the "${each.value}" as it is a list of strings. Any way around this please?

`
resource "local_file" "foo" {
  for_each = transpose(zipmap(keys(local.data), values(local.data)[*].user_assigned))
  content  = "${each.value}"
  filename = "${each.key}"
}
`

Comment: @Devopsnoob No problem. I would suggest making new question with relevant code example, error message properly formatted (not in comments) as this seems as a new issue.

Comment: sure thing. Here's the link -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65556325/how-to-correctly-use-each-value-in-for-each-in-terraform

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to do it, which I'm sharing just in case it's interesting -- the accepted answer is a fine approach too.

```
locals {
  data = {
    "project1" = {
      user_assigned = ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
    }
    "project2" = {
      user_assigned = ["user2", "user3", "user4"]
    }
  }

  project_user = flatten([
    for proj_name, proj in local.data : [
      for username in proj.user_assigned : {
        project_name = proj_name,
        username     = username
      }
    ]
  ])
}

output "example" {
  value = {
    for pu in local.project_user :
    pu.username => pu.project_name...
  }
}
```

```
Outputs:

example = {
  "user1" = [
    "project1",
  ]
  "user2" = [
    "project1",
    "project2",
  ]
  "user3" = [
    "project1",
    "project2",
  ]
  "user4" = [
    "project2",
  ]
}
```

---

I typically use this sort of approach because a data structure like that intermediate `local.project_user` value -- which is a list with an element for each project/user pair -- often ends up being useful when declaring resources that represent those pairings.

There wasn't any context in the question about what these projects and users represent or which provider they might related to, so I'm going to use `github_team` and `github_team_membership` as an example to illustrate what I mean:

```
resource "github_team" "example" {
  for_each = local.data

  name = each.key
}

resource "github_team_membership" "example" {
  for_each = {
    for pu in local.project_user : "${pu.username}:${pu.project_name}" => pu
  }

  team_id  = github_team.example[each.value.project_name].id
  username = each.value.username
}
```

Lots of providers have resources that represent a relationship between two objects like this, and so having an intermediate data structure that contains an element for each pair is a useful building block for those cases, and then you can derive from that mappings in either direction as I did in the `output "example"` in my original snippet.