# How to correctly use each.value in for_each in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I am trying to create a files for each user with the projects assigned to them as content of the file. I amunable to get the "${each.value}" as it is a list of strings. Any way around this please?

```
locals {
  data = {
    "project1" = {
      user_assigned           = ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
     }
    "project2" = {
      user_assigned           = ["user2", "user3", "user4"]
     }
  }


`
resource "local_file" "foo" {
  for_each = transpose(zipmap(keys(local.data), values(local.data)[*].user_assigned))
  content  = "${each.value}"
  filename = "${each.key}"
}
```

Error:

```
  on test.tf line 85, in resource "local_file" "foo":
  85:   content  = "${each.value}"
    |----------------
    | each.value is list of string with 2 elements
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `content` must be string, but in your case it is a list, e.g. `["project1", "project2"]`. One way to convert it to string is through [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html):

```
resource "local_file" "foo" {
  for_each = transpose(zipmap(keys(local.data), values(local.data)[*].user_assigned))
  content  = jsonencode(each.value)
  filename = each.key
}
```

Comment: @Devopsnoob No problem. Glad it worked out:-)